# Installing PostgreSQL unatended fails on Windows on a specific directory

Tags: postgresql, command-line, windows-10, postgresql-11

I need to install Postgresql 11.3 on Windows 10 with NSIS in unatended mode, for this I use the EnterpriseDB installer (https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads), but it fails with the error message "error.install.directory.nondefault". This nsis script is working fine with PosgreSQL 9.3 Windows installer.

This simple installation script bellow does not work on my development PC but works on some other PC:

```
;--------------------------------
; The name of the installer
Name "PostgreSQL 11 Installer"

; The file to write
OutFile "PostgreSQL11Installer.exe"

; Request application privileges
RequestExecutionLevel admin

;--------------------------------

;PostgreSQL Installation
Section "" 
  ExecWait 'C:\tmp\postgresql-11.3-1-windows-x64.exe  --unattendedmodeui minimal --mode unattended  --prefix C:\PostgreSQL11 --datadir C:\PostgreSQL11\data --serverport 5432 --superpassword mypassword'
SectionEnd
```

On the %TEMP% folder the bitrock_installer_xxxx.log does not show any other error message:

```
Log started 05/27/2019 at 12:24:43
Preferred installation mode : unattended
Trying to init installer in mode unattended
Mode unattended successfully initialized
Executing cscript //NoLogo "C:\Users\nducoin\AppData\Local\Temp\postgresql_installer_4263a06887\prerun_checks.vbs"
Script exit code: 0

Script output:
 The scripting host appears to be functional.

Script stderr:


[12:24:45] Using branding: PostgreSQL 11
Executing C:\Users\nducoin\AppData\Local\Temp/postgresql_installer_4263a06887/temp_check_comspec.bat 
Script exit code: 0

Script output:
 "test ok"

Script stderr:


error.install.directory.nondefault
```

It there any way to have more logs to debug this problem? Does anyone have any idea what could go wrong?

Comment: And if you run the command directly without NSIS?

Comment: C:\tmp\postgresql-11.3-1-windows-x64.exe is not your real path, maybe post your real code?

Comment: I updated the script to post the real code, the only difference being the password.
I did some more tests and found a problem, unning the command line directly when PostgreSQL 11 is not installed works fine, but when PostgreSQL is installed I have this error.install.directory.nondefault error, in a popup and in the log file.
With the full installation script however I still have the same error message even if PostgreSQL is not installed, but since I now have a working scenario I should be able to get further, thanks.

Comment: Well, I don't understand how c:\tmp can be your actual path in your script and you really should quote your path. There is no file extraction, your sample script is too minimal.

Comment: It had nothing to do with NSIS but only with PostgreSQL 11.3 installer not working for Windows 10 command line on a specific directory, I posted a question directly on EnterpriseDB forum: https://postgresrocks.enterprisedb.com/t5/PostgreSQL/Postgresql-11-command-line-installation-fails-on-Windows-for-non/m-p/3698#M299

I thought direct installation was working because when postgresql is installed in the default directory the --prefix option has no effect, postgresql is re-installed in the default directory whatever installation directory is given.

Comment: The error.install.directory.nondefault error message happens when the folder in which PostgreSQL is installed in not empty when the locale is not english, when the installation folder is not the default installation folder and when PostgreSQL is not installed yet. When it is installed the error happens if it was not installed in the default directory. The localisation problem is a bug in PostgreSQL installer, the rest is the wanted behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://postgresrocks.enterprisedb.com/t5/PostgreSQL/Postgresql-11-command-line-installation-fails-on-Windows-for-non/m-p/3698#M299

The error.install.directory.nondefault error message happens when:

- the folder in which PostgreSQL is installed in not empty
- the locale is not english
- the installation folder is not the default installation folder
- PostgreSQL is not installed yet.

When it is already installed the error happens if the previous installation was not done in the default directory.

The localisation problem is a bug in PostgreSQL installer, the rest is the wanted behaviour.

The solution to have the proper error message is to force the locale to english:
postgresql-11.3-1-windows-x64.exe --unattendedmodeui minimal --mode unattended --prefix “C:\PostgreSQL11” --datadir “C:\PostgreSQL11\data” --serverport 5432 --superpassword test --installer-language -en